# How come my refrigerator doesn't leak if I removed the ice maker?

Tags: refrigerator, ice-maker

I have a Maytag MZD2766GEQ refrigerator and my ice maker broke. I removed the assembly and everything seems fine.

What I don't understand is why isn't it leaking? I did not disconnect any water lines. My water dispenser continues to work fine.

I can't seem to find anything in the manuals that references how the water to the ice maker works. I want to make sure that I don't have a leaking time bomb in there anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

There's a valve that controls water to the ice maker.  The valve is closed which is why there is no leak.

Comment: Description of solenoid valve here: http://www.popularmechanics.com/home/improvement/electrical-plumbing/1276061

Comment: Thank you. I assumed it'd be a manual valve some where that I should close.